# Knockback when shooting ? Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im currently working on a shooter and I could not find anything that helps me with my problem. I want to make my character knock back when he shoots, but also the knockback should be different when the player uses a different weapon so he can do double jumps when shooting under himself.For example when the player is using weapon1 knockback is 2, when weapon2 then 3.

Thanks and sorry for this simple question but I am beginning to learn.

Marcel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could give each weapon a knockback or recoil value (probably a float). Then when Shoot is called on that weapon you could call a KnockBack(float amount) method on your Player. This could then use Rigdigbody.AddForce() to add a force to the player in the backwards direction of the player.

Your knockback code is then handled by the Player and each weapon retains it's own knockback amount. This should give for the ability to do things like multipliers dependant on pickups etc should you wish to do that.

I imagine the code would look something akin to below. I've not tested this code and just whipped it up in a basic text editor so copy and pasting may not work, but the logic is there. You'll have to decide how you wish to link your weapon to your player and such but that's outside the scope of the question.

Weapon.cs

```
using System.Collections;

public class Weapon
{
    private int damage;
    private float knockbackAmount;

    private Player ownerPlayer;

    public Weapon(Player ownerPlayer)
    {
        damage = 5;
        knockback = 5.0f;

        this.ownerPlayer = ownerPlayer;
    }

    public void Shoot()
    {
        // do the shooting

        ownerPlayer.Knockback(knockbackAmount);
    }
}
```

Player.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int health;

    public Player()
    {
        health = 100;
    }

    public void Knockback(float amount)
    {
        gameObject.rigidbody.AddForce(Vector3.back * amount)
    }
}
```

Comment: How would the code look like ?

Comment: @Marlex Updated my answer, this code is rough and untested but all the theory behind it should be there for you to make the connections. If you need more help I can update my code a bit later but I don't have access to Unity at the moment.